# what is need /advantage of services in android over multithreading

Tags: android

Can you explain to me:

What is the need or advantages of services in Android over multithreading?

Comment: I'm sure there's more to it than this but, services can run in the background while multithreading would run only while your app is open. Don't quote me on this but, that is my basic understanding of services.

Answer (score 6):

Benefits of `Services` over multithreading:

- When running low on memory and needing to kill existing processes, the priority of a process hosting the service will be the higher.
- You don't need an `Activity` to run.
- `Services` can be invoked through `intents`.
- You can use Permissions.

Some pitfalls:

- It runs on the ui thread.
- Use `stopSelf()` after you have finished your work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to execute a long operation and do not want to interrupt it, you should use services. By using multi-threading operating system can kill your application easily, but if you register for a service, then it will wait for finishing that operation.

To sum up, you should use a service for critical operations like uploading photo, and you can use multi-threading where interrupting the operation is not critical.